# SimpleModal crashing upon call to close modal

Tags: simplemodal

I have a div element defined as:

```
<div id="searchDialog" class="searchDialog">...</div>
```

In my code, I open the div as a modal dialog using this block of code:

```
$("#searchDialog").modal({ opacity: 70, 
                           overlayCss: { backgroundColor: "Black" }, 
                           overlayClose: false
                          });
```

When I attempt to close the dialog with this code:

```
$.modal.close();
```

I'm getting a runtime error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'remove': object is null or undefined.
```

Visual Studio debugger is highlighting the statement "a.d.overlay.remove();" in the SimpleModal javascript source.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and the browser is IE 9.  The version of SimpleModal is 1.4.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the SimpleModal library.  To fix it on your box, change

```
setTimeout(function(){
    // opera work-around
    s.d.overlay.remove();

    // reset the dialog object
    s.d = {};
}, 10);
```

to

```
setTimeout(function(){
    // opera work-around
    if (s.d.overlay){
        s.d.overlay.remove();
    }

    // reset the dialog object
    s.d = {};
}, 10);
```

[See the SimpleModal bug tracker for details](http://code.google.com/p/simplemodal/issues/detail?id=48).